# Does a DHCP client is expected to send DHCP request unicast to the Server in the event of a Unplug/replug or eth0 down and up?

Tags: dhcp, linux

I would like to understand if the DHCP client running in our embedded device is expected to send DHCP request unicasted to the server in the following events?

1. Eth0 goes down and comes back online
2. Physically Unplugging the ethernet cable

As per a normal dhcp client running in the Windows 10 machine,It does send the unicast message in the event of unplug and disable/enable the interface.However the RFC 2131 doesn't explicitly states the behaviour. Or have I missed some points in the RFC??

Comment: So,is it mandatory for a client to send dhcp request once the link comes up unplug/interface disable/enable ? It cannot start sending the packets without getting ack from dhcp server. Isn't it?

Comment: That doesn't make the question on-topic for this site.

Comment: I already tried asking in serverfault.Nobody answered the question there but i knew the NE fraternity will be able to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the link goes through a down-up cycle a client should repeat its DHCP discovery-request process. It could have moved to a completely different network. This is detailed in RFC2131 *3.7. When clients should use DHCP*.

The cause of the unlink-relink cycle doesn't matter. From the NIC's perspective there's no difference between deactivating the uplink port and physically removing the patch cable.

Comment: Thanks Zac67. One more query,If the client was having an IPsec session over 6in4 tunnel then where does the next DHCP packet (DHCP request) get routed(during down-up cycle)? Will the packet get routed over the tunnel or will it reach the immediate DHCP server?

Comment: DHCP is a protocol implemented over a broadcast/unicast network (usually Ethernet) and not normally present in tunnels. IPsec is (most often) an unnumbered tunnel that provides a virtual end-to-end link. 6in4 requires a local IPv4 address that is provided by local DHCP in your case. A physical link-up should be followed by DHCPv4, 6in4 tunnel setup, and IPsec tunnel setup.

Comment: I'd like to clarify an emphasis on the word "SHOULD" (which is capitalized in the text of [RFC 2131 section 3.7: When clients should use DHCP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2131#section-3.7)), but that is intended to be a recommended practice rather than "an absolute requirement" (as phrased by [RFC 2119 section 1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2119#section-1).  A client ought to be able to count on the IP address continuing to be reserved for that client, until the lease expires.

Comment: "SHOULD" is defined in practically every RFC as "you have to unless you have good reason to deviate and it's your responsibility", see section 1.4.